# Determine scaling in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, zooming, scaling

So I'm running into an issue with Windows 10 users in my database. For a lot of users, the default scaling (or zoom) is set to 125% or 150% since they have a high resolution monitor. I have no issues handling different resolutions as I know a function to determine it, but I cannot find a way to determine what users have their their scaling set at. Due to this, my forms are missized and many are too large and do not fit on the screen. Is there a way in vba to determine the scaling that a user has?

Answer (score 0):

Second post here as the solution:

https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-determine-the-dpi-setting-for-current-user.2521177/